# Is there a component for designing the report(jasperreport) at runtime?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have some reports(jrxml files) that users want to be able to modify them at runtime graphically.

Is there a component for designing the report(jasperreport) at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JasperDesign](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html) object to modify the template at runtime. 
Also you can look at [dynamic jasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/) for creating the design at runtime.